# Not sure why I can't get the values of this array or decode the json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am making a call to an API which should return a JSON array. I receive this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"msg_id":"0t5OxT1ZP9VcF45L2","_text":"I want to reserve","entities":{"intent":[{"confidence":1,"value":"make_reservation","type":"value"}]}}
)
```

I know it's JSON because a) the docs say that's what I should be getting and b) I ran `isJson($response)` and got `true`.

I have tried to use `json_decode`but the code just dies when I do (it errs saying it's expecting a string and got an array which makes sense but if I do `json_encode` that would just further encode the json from what I can understand).

As I understand it, I just need a way to traverse this array and get the `"value:" key` inside `entities: intent:`. However I can't figure out how to get it or where I'm wrong.

I have tried doing:

`$val = $jsonArray[0]['entitites']['intent'][0]['value']` but nothing comes out.

Comment: `json_decode($jsonArray[0])`? The whole array isn't json, just the results contain a json string

Comment: What you posted isn't valid json, you should be getting back "{"msg_id":"0t5OxT1ZP9VcF45L2","_text":"I want to reserve","entities":{"intent":[{"confidence":1,"value":"make_reservation","type":"value"}]}}"

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yep, that was it. Thank you. Could you put it as an answer so I can mark you as the right one, please?

Comment: @user6673915 yes one moment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decode a PHP array that has encoded values.

You should try `json_decode($jsonArray[0])` instead, so that you decode the value of the first array key, as that is the actual json string.

Answer (score 1):

The data you posted is a php array where the value of the first element of the array is a json string.

```
json_decode($response[0]);
```